# Read more doesn't work in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have problem in mobile screen with my Wordpress blog,
read more button doesn't work also the screen size doesn't fit on mobile

abood250.com

Style.css

```
    /* =Global
----------------------------------------------- */
body {
  color: #6B6B6B;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-size: 14px;
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: embed;


}

a {
  color: #1FA67A;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
       -o-transition: all 0.2s;
          transition: all 0.2s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  color: #1FA67A;
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h5,
.h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h6,
.h6 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

img {
  height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
  max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%; /* Corrects font size not being inherited in all browsers */
  margin: 0; /* Addresses margins set differently in IE6/7, F3/4, S5, Chrome */
  vertical-align: baseline; /* Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers */
  *vertical-align: middle; /* Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers */
}
select {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #DCE4EC;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  padding: 0; /* Addresses excess padding in IE8/9 */
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* Addresses appearance set to searchfield in S5, Chrome */
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* Addresses box sizing set to border-box in S5, Chrome (include -moz to future-proof) */
  -moz-box-sizing:    content-box;
  box-sizing:         content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration { /* Corrects inner padding displayed oddly in S5, Chrome on OSX */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { /* Corrects inner padding and border displayed oddly in FF3/4 www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/14/the-devils-in-the-details-fixing-dojos-toolbar-buttons/ */
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
textarea {
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  color: #111;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  padding: 3px;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto; /* Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE6/7/8/9 */
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  vertical-align: top; /* Improves readability and alignment in all browsers */
  width: 100%;
}


/* Alignment */
.alignright {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.alignleft {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.aligncenter {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  position: absolute !important;
}

.screen-reader-text:hover,
.screen-reader-text:active,
.screen-reader-text:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  clip: auto !important;
  color: #21759b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: auto;
  right: 5px;
  left: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 15px 23px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 5px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar */
}

/* Clearing */
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:before,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clear:after,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* =Content
----------------------------------------------- */

.sticky {
}
.hentry {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
.byline,
.updated {
  display: none;
}
.single .byline,
.group-blog .byline {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.page-content,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}
.page-links {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}




/* =Post styling
----------------------------------------------- */
.entry-meta a {
  font-size: 13px;
}
#main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;

}

.entry-meta a {
  color: #6B6B6B;
}
.entry-meta .fa {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #1FA67A;
}
.entry-meta span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.entry-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #444;

}
.entry-title a {
  color: #444;
}
.entry-title a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.btn.btn-default.read-more {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  color: #1FA67A;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-Bottom: -40px;


}
.btn.btn-default.read-more:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1FA67A;
}
.search .btn.btn-default.read-more {
  float: none;

}
hr.section-divider {
  border-color: #E8E8E8;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    float: right;
}


/* =Singe Post/Page Pagination
----------------------------------------------- */
.page-links span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.page-links a span {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  color: #1FA67A;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
       -o-transition: all 0.2s;
          transition: all 0.2s;
}
.page-links a:hover span {
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  border: 1px solid #1FA67A;
  color: #fff;
}
/* =Asides
----------------------------------------------- */

.blog .format-aside .entry-title,
.archive .format-aside .entry-title {
  display: none;
}

/* =Media
----------------------------------------------- */

.page-content img.wp-smiley,
.entry-content img.wp-smiley,
.comment-content img.wp-smiley {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wp-caption {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.wp-caption img[class*="wp-image-"] {
  display: block;
}
.wp-caption-text {
  text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
  margin: 0.8075em 0;
}
.site-main .gallery {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.gallery-caption {
}
.site-main .gallery a img {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
}
.site-main .gallery dd {
  margin: 0;
}
.site-main .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
}
.site-main .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item img {
}

.thumbnail {

float: right;
}




/* Make sure embeds and iframes fit their containers */
embed,
iframe,
object {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* =Widgets
----------------------------------------------- */

.widget {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* Make sure select elements fit in widgets */
.widget select {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Search widget */
.widget_search .search-submit {
  display: none;
}
.widget > ul > li,
li.recentcomments {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.widget ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.widget ul {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.widget-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.widget ul.nav.nav-tabs {
  padding: 0;
}
.tab-content ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
#secondary .widget_archive ul li:before,
#secondary .widget_categories ul li:before,
#secondary .widget_recent_comments ul li:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#secondary .widget_archive ul li:before {
  content: '\f073';
}
#secondary .widget_categories ul li:before {
  content: '\f115';
}
#secondary .widget_recent_comments ul li:before {
  content: '\f0e5';
}
.tab-content .tab-thumb {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.tab-content li {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0 0 6px;
}
.tab-content .tab-entry {
  display: block;
}
.tab-content > .active {
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-top: none;
}
.tab-content ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.tab-content .tab-entry {
  font-size: 14px
}
.tab-comment {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tab-content i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.tab-thumb.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.tab-content #messages li:before {
  content: '\f0e5';
  font-family: fontawesome;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1FA67A;
}

/* =Buttons
----------------------------------------------- */
.btn-default, .label-default {
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  border-color: #1FA67A;
}
.btn-default:hover, .label-default[href]:hover, .label-default[href]:focus, .btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus, .btn-default:active, .btn-default.active, #image-navigation .nav-previous a:hover, #image-navigation .nav-next a:hover {
  background-color: #1b926c;
  border-color: #1b926c;
}
.btn.btn-default {
    color: #FFF;
}
/* =Infinite Scroll
----------------------------------------------- */

/* Globally hidden elements when Infinite Scroll is supported and in use. */
.infinite-scroll .paging-navigation, /* Older / Newer Posts Navigation (always hidden) */
.infinite-scroll.neverending .site-footer { /* Theme Footer (when set to scrolling) */
  display: none;
}

/* When Infinite Scroll has reached its end we need to re-display elements that were hidden (via .neverending) before */
.infinity-end.neverending .site-footer {
  display: block;
}
#infinite-handle span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  color: #1FA67A;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
       -o-transition: all 0.2s;
          transition: all 0.2s;
}
#infinite-handle span:hover {
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  color: #fff;
}
.woocommerce #infinite-handle {
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations label {
  color: #6B6B6B;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

/* =Custom Styles
----------------------------------------------- */
.site-branding {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.site-description {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 16px;

}
.page-template-page-homepage-php .carousel {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* =Navigation
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-main [class*="navigation"] a,
.more-link {
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;

}
.site-main [class*="navigation"] a:hover,
.more-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1FA67A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.more-link {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.site-main [class*="navigation"] {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous {
  float: right;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #999;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
  color: #1FA67A;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  align-self: center;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1FA67A;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #999;
}
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: #999;
}
.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  border: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a {
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
}
/* =Comments
----------------------------------------------- */

.comment-content a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.bypostauthor {
}
#respond {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
#respond > p, #respond p.comment-notes, p.logged-in-as {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
p.logged-in-as {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.comment-list {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.comment .comment-body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding-right: 116px;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.comment-list .children {
  margin-right: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-left: none;
}
.comment-list li.comment > div img.avatar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 29px;
  left: auto;
  top: 29px;
}
#comment-form-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.vcard .avatar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 29px;
  left: auto;
  top: 29px;
}
.comment-metadata {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.comment-reply-link {
  float: left;
}
.form-allowed-tags code {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: inherit;
}
.comment-respond label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.comment-respond .required {
  color: #C7254E;
}


/* =Attachment styling
----------------------------------------------- */
#image-navigation .nav-previous a,
#image-navigation .nav-next a{
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
}
#image-navigation .nav-previous a:hover,
#image-navigation .nav-next a:hover{
  background-color: #1FA67A;
  color: #fff;
}
#image-navigation .nav-previous,
#image-navigation .nav-next {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

/* =Footer
----------------------------------------------- */

#footer-area {
  background-color: #313233;
  color: #CCC;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#footer-area a {
  color: #ccc;
}
#footer-area .footer-widget-area {
  padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footer-area ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
#footer-area .site-info nav ul li {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#footer-area .tab-content > .active {
  border: none;
}
#footer-area .nav-tabs > li.active > a, #footer-area .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, #footer-area .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#footer-area .tab-content .tab-entry {
  font-size: inherit;
}
#footer-area .widgettitle {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#footer-area #social ul li {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#footer-area .widget ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.footer-nav.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
.footer-nav.nav {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.copyright {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#colophon {
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #3A3A3A;



}
.site-info a {
  color: #777;


}
.site-info a:hover {
  color: #999;
}
#footer-area a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.site-info {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 5px;

}
.footer-nav.nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.scroll-to-top {
  background: #3B3B3B;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  bottom: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  right: auto;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
       -o-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
          transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}
.scroll-to-top:hover {
  background: #1FA67A;
  opacity: .8;
}

/* =Mobile Styling
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .pull-left {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .site-info, .copyright {
      text-align: right;

  }

  .footer-nav.nav, .copyright {
    float: none;

  }

  .site-content {
    width: 66%;
}

  .flex-caption {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }

  #footer-area {
  display: none;
  }

}

/* =Social icons
----------------------------------------------- */

.top-bar {
    border-bottom-color: #E8E8E8;
}
#social a {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 6px;
    color: #E8E8E8;
}
#social {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#social ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#social ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#social li a span {
  display: none;
}
.fa-googleplus:before {
  content: "\f0d5";
}
#social li,
#social ul {
    border: 0!important;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#social li a[href*="twitter.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-twitter:before {
    content: "\f099"
}
#social li a[href*="facebook.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-facebook-f:before,
.fa-facebook:before {
    content: "\f09a"
}
#social li a[href*="github.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-github:before {
    content: "\f09b"
}
#social li a[href*="/feed"] .fa:before,
.fa-rss:before {
    content: "\f09e"
}
#social li a[href*="pinterest.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-pinterest:before {
    content: "\f0d2"
}
#social li a[href*="plus.google.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-google-plus:before {
    content: "\f0d5"
}
#social li a[href*="linkedin.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-linkedin:before {
    content: "\f0e1"
}
#social li a[href*="youtube.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-youtube:before {
    content: "\f167"
}
#social li a[href*="instagram.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-instagram:before {
    content: "\f16d"
}
#social li a[href*="flickr.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-flickr:before {
    content: "\f16e"
}
#social li a[href*="tumblr.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-tumblr:before {
    content: "\f173"
}
#social li a[href*="dribbble.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-dribbble:before {
    content: "\f17d"
}
#social li a[href*="skype.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-skype:before {
    content: "\f17e"
}
#social li a[href*="foursquare.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-foursquare:before {
    content: "\f180"
}
#social li a[href*="vimeo.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-vimeo-square:before {
    content: "\f194"
}
#social li a[href*="spotify.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-spotify:before {
    content: "\f1bc"
}
#social li a[href*="soundcloud.com"] .fa:before,
.fa-soundcloud:before {
    content: "\f1be"
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .site-branding {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #social {
    top: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .side-pull-left .main-content-inner, .side-pull-right .main-content-inner{
    float: none;

  }


}

/* =Call For Action
----------------------------------------------- */

.cfa{
  padding: 30px 0px;
  background: #1FA67A;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cfa-text{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.cfa-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.cfa-button a,
.cfa-button a {
  color: #fff;
}
.cfa-button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #1FA67A;
}
.cfa-button:hover a {
    color: #1FA67A;
}
/* Layout */
.side-pull-left #primary{
    float: left;


}
.side-pull-right #primary{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 330px;


}
.no-sidebar #secondary, .full-width #secondary{
    display: none;


}
.no-sidebar #primary{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.full-width #primary{
    width: 100%;
}
```

======================================================================

mobile codes

```
 /* =Mobile Styling
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .pull-left {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .site-info, .copyright {
      text-align: right;

  }

  .footer-nav.nav, .copyright {
    float: none;

  }

  .site-content {
    width: 66%;
}

  .flex-caption {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }

  #footer-area {
  display: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: What the?? You pasted your entire project here? :O

Comment: can you create a snippet which recreates your problem?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sorry I edited my post and added only mobile styling codes

Answer (score 0):

Remove this CSS.

```
.side-pull-right #primary {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 330px;
}
```

and read bootstrap grid system.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

PS: in mobile maybe you need to use `col-xs-` class.